# Best ORM for a MVC 5 (.NET 4.5) application

Tags: entity-framework, orm

We are about to start MVC 5 application using SQL Server and MYSql DBs.

Please help me to select the most reliable ORM considetring Performance, Roadmap, Support, Documentation, easy to learn/maintain etc.

I have considered following ORMs -

Entity Framework
 1) nHibernate 3.3
 2) EF 6.0 
 3) BL Toolkit

Also share me the performance statistics(latest versions)

Comment: http://www.devbridge.com/articles/entity-framework-6-vs-nhibernate-4/

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is LinqToSQL. It does not have the best gui for managing objects, but the performance is good and you can easily enable it for bulk transactions.